# Scrape webpage with unstable class

Tags: javascript, cheerio

```
var summary = $(".job-ad-details-72250").text();
```

above is a js path from a web page. I want to extract content from that path but unfortunately, the

class which I should use to extract content has a number(72250) and it keeps on changing. meaning

its only useful on one page, the number changes if is another page. is there a way  i can put a

constant kind of?

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question without knowing how the number changes OR how the web page looks like (html). Either you have to know how it changes and each time search for a different class name, appending the correct number, either get the element by another query. So please add the info to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can match partial class:

```
$('[class*="job-ad-details-"]')
```